# Is backupAgent attribute necessary for application element?

Tags: android, android-manifest

The documentation for AndroidManifest.xml says: `There is no default. The name must be specified.` on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

But I have the code for a working sample project that does not include it.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use backup agent - you have to provide this attribute. Otherwise your application will work without backups.